# Make the Object to stick at the top of the screen SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How to stop the object that moves from the bottom of the screen to the top. And object should stick to top. Here is the code for that object:

```
    SKSpriteNode* ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"ball.png"];
    ball.name = ballCategoryName;
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/3, self.frame.size.height/3);
    [self addChild:ball];

    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2];

    ball.physicsBody.friction = 1.0f;

    ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;

    ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;

    ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;


    [ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0f, -10.0f)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) checkPosition
{
    if (ball.position.y > self.height.size) {
        ball.position.y = ball.position.y - 1;
    }
}

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self checkPosition];    //update tests rough 60 times per sec.
}
```

Comment: if you din't mind can you explain me. How to check updates. I am new to sprite kit.

Comment: I edited my answer. For more information https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

Comment: It worked after making some modification. You give me hint where we can modify the Node. Thanks